# Installing private github dependency not creating npm_modules folder

Tags: node.js, github, npm

I have a very simple project uploaded to a private repo on Github which I am trying to add as a dependency and install in a local project. The private repo contains

- package.json
- index.js : contains 2 lines of code to export an object using module.exports
- README

Now I am 89% sure I have used private access tokens and the correct format to include the repo as a dependency.

My local package.json looks like :

"dependencies": {
    "private-repo": "git+https://0000000000:x-oauth-basic@github.com/ABC/private-reponame.git"
  }

"npm install" does not throw any errors either but I don't see any node_modules folder created. Is there anything specific I may be missing in the package.json of the private repo which could prevent node_modules from being created? I am expecting that after npm install, node_modules gets created with a sub folder called "private-repo".

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you try once more with `npm i --loglevel silly` for a more verbose logging?

Comment: I did, what am I looking for? the folder did not get created